# VBA copy row to certain sheet based on cell data plus age sort

Tags: vba, excel

I received some help here before and need to update my code.  Right now it takes the row on the "MASTER" sheet and copies it to a new sheet (BLACK, 1ST BROWN,...).  I would like it to still do that but also copy it to a second sheet (BLACK NOTES, 1ST BROWN,...) but if (cell e<=12) it copies it to "KIDS NOTES" and not the (BLACK NOTES, 1ST BROWN,...)

Thank you

```
Sub RUN_BEFORE_TEST()

 sortlist Macro

  Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim o As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    j = 11
    k = 11
    l = 11
    m = 11
    n = 11
    o = 11
    p = 11

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("master")

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("D10:D110"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("C10:C110"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("B10").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("B11:B110"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        CustomOrder:= _
        "6th Black,5th Black,4th Black,3rd Black,2nd Black,1st Black,Jr. Black,1st Brown,2nd Brown,3rd Brown", _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("Table2").sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

For Each c In Source.Range("b11:b110")
        If (c = "6th Black" Or c = "5th Black" Or c = "4th Black" Or c = "3rd Black" Or c = "2nd Black" Or c = "1st Black" Or c = "Jr. Black") Then
           Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BLACK")
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
        ElseIf c = "1st Brown" Then
            Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1ST BROWN")
            Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(k)
            k = k + 1
        ElseIf c = "2nd Brown" Then
            Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2ND BROWN")
            Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(l)
            l = l + 1
        ElseIf c = "3rd Brown" Then
            Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("3RD BROWN")
            Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(m)
            m = m + 1
        End If

        j = j + 1
        Next c

Sheets("BLACK").Select

Set oRng = Range("b11")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""

End Sub
```

Here is your code inserted.  One thing I forgot to mention is that if c=*black I don't want it to move to "kids".

```
For Each c In Source.Range("b11:b110")
' new condition to check cell e
If (c.Offset(0, 2) <= 12) Then
   Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KIDS BROWN NOTES")
ElseIf (c = "6th Black" Or c = "5th Black" Or c = "4th Black" Or c = "3rd Black" Or c = "2nd Black" Or c = "1st Black" Or c = "Jr. Black") Then
   Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BLACK")
   Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
    If (c = "6th Black" Or c = "5th Black" Or c = "4th Black" Or c = "3rd Black" Or c = "2nd Black" Or c = "1st Black" Or c = "Jr. Black") Then
       Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BLACK")
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
    ElseIf c = "1st Brown" Then
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1ST BROWN")
        Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(k)
        k = k + 1
    ElseIf c = "2nd Brown" Then
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2ND BROWN")
        Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(l)
        l = l + 1
    ElseIf c = "3rd Brown" Then
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("3RD BROWN")
        Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(m)
        m = m + 1
    End If

    j = j + 1
    Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stick with your style of coding ... I don't exactly agree with it but here

```
For Each c In Source.Range("b11:b110")
    ' new condition to check cell e
    if ( c.offset(0, 3) <= 12 and Instr(1, c, "black", vbcomparemethod.vbtextcompare) <= 0) then 
       Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KIDS NOTES")
    elseIf (c = "6th Black" Or c = "5th Black" Or c = "4th Black" Or c = "3rd Black" Or c = "2nd Black" Or c = "1st Black" Or c = "Jr. Black") Then
       Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BLACK")
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
    ...
enter code here
```

Hopefully someone will upload a more optimized version for you

Comment: Thank you.  I'm trying to learn more about this.  What would you have done different?

Comment: Hello J.  I'm getting a compile error.  Next without for.  It's after j=j+1

Comment: it's after,  j=j+1   next c

Comment: Hi Brian, if the code is the same with only the change I made you should not get said compile error. Unfortunately, I would need to see the code to tell you what's missing. It's not necessarily the for:next combination, could be a missing 'end if'

Comment: What would you have done different? >> Sorting is very expensive, I would not do this. Copy-Paste is also expensive, not sure I would do this. You can read the entire range once, reading a variable is faster than reading cells. You can copy a union of ranges and then perform one paste. When I learned this, I probably would've had the same code as you but no one told me half of what I know today :(

Comment: I just put the new code up in the original question.

Comment: There is a missing `End If ` that should probably go between `j=j+1` and `next c` Yes, it's due to the if I added, you have to close it off

Comment: To not move to kids if * black change the `if c.offset ...` to `if ( c.offset(0, 3) <= 12 and InStr(1, c, "black", , VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare) > 0 ) then`

Comment: Thank you for all your help J.  I am not getting the error anymore but it is not copying any of the other data now.  Only the Black that is over 12.

Comment: Sorry about that, see the answer edit, I made a typo in my comment